# How to list all tables in MySQL database which match a keyword and ended with year?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, information-schema

How to list all tables in MySQL database which match like `"bl_pelanggan"+YEAR`?

currently I use the following query:

`SHOW TABLES LIKE 'bl_pelanggan%'`

but it list all of these:

[image]

I want only inside the red box, how to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try something like this,

```
SELECT table_name, table_type, ENGINE
       FROM information_schema.tables
       WHERE table_schema = 'your schema name' AND table_name REGEXP '[[:digit:]]$'AND table_name LIKE 'bl_pelanggan%'
       ORDER BY table_name;
```

Comment: it worked! but I assume it'll list all table which ended with number, how to filter only table which starts with "bl_pelanggan"?

Comment: ` AND table_name LIKE 'bl_pelanggan%'`

Comment: thank you very much rahulsm an @bato3, this method more convenient for me than other answers.

Answer (score 2):

```
SHOW TABLES LIKE 'bl_pelanggan____'
```

Comment: this be valid for `bl_pelanggan_abc`. (4 letter sufix)

Comment: really a short way ... but I agree with @bato3 comment

Answer (score 2):

This should also be possible:

```
show tables from <your_schema_name> where tables_in_<your_schema_name> like "bl_pelanggan201%";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SHOW TABLES FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA 
WHERE Tables_in_information_schema LIKE 'bl_pelanggan201%'
```

You can check http://rextester.com/AOVZ31733